# Syntax specific highlighting with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext

I'm wondering if there is a way to have two different tag colours ("colors" for those in the US) for different language tags in the same file.

For example, lets say I have ColdFusion code and HTML code in the same .cfm file. Could I make the ColdFusion tags red and the HTML tags Blue?

For instance, lets call the below file *HelloWorld.cfm* - could I colour the tags differently?

```
<cfset myvar = "hello, world" />
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is my title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div><cfoutput>#myvar#</cfoutput></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Yes, as long as the tags can be identified as having different scopes by your installed language definitions, you can edit your colour scheme to target those scopes with specific colours and other styles.

In your packages folder, language scopes are defined in the .tmLanguage files for your installed languages, while styles are defined in the .tmTheme files in the "color scheme - default" folder.

If you position your cursor inside a tag, and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>-p</kbd> in OSX I think) the status bar will display the current scope. You can also copy this to the clipboard via the console with this command:

```
sublime.set_clipboard(view.syntax_name(view.sel()[0].b))
```

You can use this information to create your styles, a bit like css selectors, but with XML. For example I use this [Coldfusion package](https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion) and I have the scope selectors shown below in my custom .tmTheme file to distinguish cf tags from HTML tags.

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Tag name</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>entity.name.tag</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#D8D0B6</string>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>bold</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#647A4F</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>CF tag name</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>entity.name.tag.conditional.cfml, entity.name.tag.declaration.cfml, entity.name.tag.other, entity.name.tag.cf, entity.name.tag.inline.other.cfml</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#D8D0B6</string>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>bold</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#990033</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

More info on [scope selectors](http://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this is **exactly** what I'm looking for. Kudos!

Comment: @NotJustClarkKent: It would be appropriate then to mark this excellent answer as “the answer” (by clicking on the check-mark).

Answer (score 4):

I've updated the `ColdFusion.tmLanguage` so that you'll only need to target `entity.name.tag.cf` to color all cf tags. You can also target specific tags for example `entity.name.tag.cf.script` or `entity.name.tag.cf.query` for `cfscript` and `cfquery` respectively.
HTH

Comment: Thanks Atomi :) -- I'm playing around with these entity targets now but I fear might be having _too_ _much_ fun ;)