# Sublime Text 2: build system custom selector

Tags: build-automation, sublimetext2

How can I define a selector in the build system with the custom extension (like `*.ltx`, `*.cmake` etc) for which there is no available selector (like `text.tex.latex`, `source.c++` etc)?

Is it possible? If yes - how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible, if you define a new syntax definition (i.e., a new .tmLanguage file). Syntax definitions can declare new 'scope names' which you can then use in your new, custom build systems.

The new syntax definition file doesn't actually have to define/match the file's syntax, as you can simply match by file extension...!

Take a look [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#creating-a-new-syntax-definition) at the .tmLanguage file syntax. The "scopeName" item allows you to name your new scope (i.e., "text.tex.latex", etc.). I'll go through an example below.

---

I created a new syntax which defined a new scope -- it was quite easy (like most things in Sublime):

- In the Command Palette, select 'Package Control: Install Package'
- In the list of packages, select 'PackageDev'
- Create a new syntax definition by selecting **Tools > Packages > Package Development > New Syntax Definition**
- Your new syntax definition will look like this:

```
{ "name": "Syntax Name",
  "scopeName": "source.syntax_name",
  "fileTypes": [""],
  "patterns": [
  ],
  "uuid": "..."
}
```

... replace "Syntax Name" with a descriptive name, "source.syntax_name" with your new scope name, and fill in "fileTypes" to contain one or more file extensions. For instance:

`"fileTypes": ["tex", "ltx"]`

- Save the file using an ".JSON-tmLanguage" extension under Packages/User
- Select **Tools > Build System > Select Json to tmLanguage**
- Select **Tools > Build**

You're done! Any new files which happen to have one of the extensions defined in "fileTypes" will activate the "scopeName" scope.

You can now use this scope in a new Build System file (**Tools > Build System > New Build System...**)

Cheers!

Comment: Could I use this to make the \section{text} headings bigger in Latex code like in Textmate 2? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98574/textmate-2-how-can-increase-font-size-of-sections-in-the-markup-code

Comment: @macmadness86 unfortunately, no. I've looked a bit at what I could find about the .tmTheme syntax, and it seems that it only supports a 'fontStyle' (of which Sublime supports 'bold' and 'italic') and 'foreground' and 'background' colors. I've tried to set a custom 'fontSize' setting to no avail. See here (especially in the comments): http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/20780-implement-fontstyle-in-tmtheme/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345222/syntax-specific-highlighting-with-sublime-text-2 as well