# highlight coloration in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

I don't understand how, in this example, the color is match with this regular expression.

```
name: logfile
scopeName: source.log
fileTypes:
- log
patterns:
- match: \b(ERROR|Error)\b
  name: constant.language.log
uuid: 8728e0fe-14c6-4374-acde-da1857d0a378
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please [edit] it and add additional details.

Comment: In sublime text we can make our own highlight coloration with the package :  AAAPackageDev. The coloration is based on regex detection. In this exemple i understand how the regex is built but not how the color is associated.

Comment: Yes you can. And... ?

Comment: And i don't see how a color is associated with a regex.

Comment: I saw this example in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221150/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-2) if it can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML in your question is compiled by PackageDev into a `.tmLanguage` XML/Plist format. Each regex is associated with one or more [scopes](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes). A scope is essentially just a specific region in an editing buffer with a name, in this case `constant.language.log`. As buffers are modified, Sublime (and TextMate, where the idea originally came from) scans the text for matches to the regexes in the `.tmLanguage` syntax definition file, and names them appropriately. In this case, anywhere the word `ERROR` or `Error` appears on its own, it is assigned the `constant.language.log` scope.

The coloring comes from your color scheme, the `.tmTheme` file shown in your User Preferences. Color scheme files are also XML-based, but instead of containing regexes they contain [scope selectors](http://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors#scope_selectors), similar to CSS selectors, if you are familiar with them. Each scope selector can be assigned a foreground color, a background color, and/or bold or italic text. So, for example, a color scheme may have the selector `constant` (which will match `constant.language`, `constant.environment`, etc.) and rules to color it purple and make the text bold and italic. Now, every time Sublime assigns the selector `constant.*` to a region, the color scheme will style that region according to its rules.